# Ruby on Rails / ActiveRecord and Table Partitions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-partitioning

I've read the documentation and been able to find anything to assist me so far.  I've also read a large number of blog articles, but nothing seems to answer my question directly:

**Is it possible to manage table partitions in an InnoDB table with ActiveRecord?**  I'd really prefer to keep things very clean and I'm trying to avoid writing external scripts to try to automate the creation/deletion of partitions over time.

Comment: What partition management do you want?

Comment: @RickJames Well, let's start with any kind at all.  I'm currently running partitions across date ranges that are two days wide.  I'm unaware of any kind of built in management for partitions with Rails at all, nor have I come across any gems that purport to do it in any kind of intelligent way.

Comment: What is your ultimate objective with manual partitioning?  Perhaps you are trying to skin the cat in the wrong way, and there is a less manual process (e.g., adding appropriate indexes)?  ActiveRecord is an abstraction, and adding support for something that MySQL already tries to abstract away (AFAIK) would seem to be quite leaky indeed.

Comment: We have a massive number of rows (hundreds of millions).  The index for the entire table is > 256 gigs.  Partitioning the table brings the index down to a reasonable value that can be kept in RAM, vastly improving performance.

Comment: By the way, before you say you must have too much data in the rows, the table in question has only three columns.  It's a join table that has only integers in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An additional solution has emerged since I first asked this question. While the solution does require the use of Postgresql over MySQL or Maria, this isn't a high hurdle since it is more or less the default database for Rails.

The [Partitioned](https://github.com/fiksu/partitioned) gem on Github specifically handles all of the partitioning mechanics in a nice, Railsy way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!
But I don't think that there is a gem that will do it for you.

In order to perform partition management you need to do the hard work by yourself and send the command that you need to run on the DB directly via the connection in the following way

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE your_table drop partition p0")
```

Comment: Mm..  What this says is, "There's nothing built in to support it so do the raw SQL yourself.."  Not exactly what I'm looking for. If I have to do the SQL myself I wouldn't bother with all of the overhead of loading the Rails framework first.. I'd just keep using the scripts that I have.

Comment: there are several tools to manage partitions for postreSQL, may be you should try it instead of MySQL or write this gem yourself and make good to all rails programmers on earth.

Comment: I use partitions in mysql extensively and have never come across anything other than using raw SQL in activerecord to define and manage them.

Comment: for Postgres List partition, it's `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('DROP TABLE  p0;')`, where p0 is partition name, in case anyone stumbles across this.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see how ActiveRecord could do things like `DROP PARTITION` and `REORGANIZE PARTITION`.  Can it even call a Stored procedure?  If so, then build one similar to what is in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) and call it from Rails.

Comment: Yet migrations absolutely support it.